# Magento 2 customizing category page

Tags: magento2, layout, category-view

I want to customize the category page and I am using the below file path:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml**

Below is xml file code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_banner" template="category/banner.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="-"/>   
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_desc_main_column" template="category/desc_main_column.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="category.products"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="category.image" destination="content" before="category_desc_main_column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
</body>
```

I have gone to the admin panel and Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront but I can't find any file which I can add my custom element before `section` element.

When I go to the inspect element it's creating the below HTML structure:

[image: inspect element]

> I want to move the breadcrumbs div in the `section` and want to add
>   two new DIV's before `section` element.

How I can edit the `catalog_category_view.xml` file code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To add two new `div`s before the `section` element try this layout xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <container name="div-one" before="navigation.sections" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="div-one">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">One</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <container name="div-two" before="navigation.sections" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="div-two">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">Two</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can move the breadcrumbs into `navigation-sections` like this:

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="store.menu"/>
```

However, there's a css rule that prevents it from displaying so you need to make a new rule for it:

```
.nav-sections .breadcrumbs {
    display: block;
}
```

**Update**

Here how to get nested `div`s with `breadcrumbs` and `sections` inside.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <container name="divone" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="divone">
                <container name="divtwo" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="divtwo">
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="navigation.sections" destination="divtwo"/>
        <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="divtwo" before="navigation.sections"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks Aarom, div's element added before `section`, but how I can add the `section` in between both `div` elements.

Comment: you would put `after="navigation.sections"` instead of `before="navigation.sections"` for the one that is below `section`.

Comment: Thanks the `after` and `before` is working fine but I want html structure like this: [please see here](http://prntscr.com/emlvt1).

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine for `breadcrumbs` div, but not for `section` element. please see this [snap](http://prntscr.com/emytwc)

Comment: I don't have a `section` element in my 2.1.4 installation, instead there is a `div` with the class name of `sections` and I was able to move it using above code. Maybe you are using an older version or some 3rd party extension?

Comment: No, I am using Magento ver. 2.1.5 version and category page. I haven't use the any 3ed party extension. Thanks for your help, but I now just want to move the `section` element in the `divtwo`.